# How much space is allocated for String in SQLite?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, windows-8, microsoft-metro

```
class anyClass
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string field { get; set; }
 }
```

In **SQLite**,
For an object with 25 characters *field* length, will it take space for 25 characters or it always acquires space for **MaxLength** of the *field*?

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: For most entries _field_ length will be at max 25 characters while for some it may go much higher.If the space taken depends on  _field_ length only(not on **MaxLength**) the i don't have anyting to worry about else i will have to store entries with bigger length in separate table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite, as most other databases with VARCHAR types, will store only actual characters entered into the column.

Please also note that SQLite doesn't have column lengths, you can enter a string of any supported length into a column.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i have one more question, if SQLite doesn't have column length then why do we  need to provide **MaxLength**?